# Is the "Ishanya" direction connected with Siva?

Tags: shiva, vastu-shastra

Ishanya refers to the Northeast direction in Vastu Shastra and "Ishana" is a name of Siva.  Is there a connection?

Answer (score 5):

[Varaha Purana, Chapter 76](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/the-varaha-purana/vol-i/chapter-76), describes the Asta Dikpala (eight guardians of directions) and according to this, Ishana is the ruler of north-eastern direction.

> 1-2. On the resplendent eastern part of Meru full of different minerals and in the form of a circular extension, there is the city of the immortals full of mighty gods and demons, full of gold and with well-devised pathways and arches.
>   3-5. To its north-east with hundreds of spires and extensive lakes, decerated with flowers and flags, is the prosperous city of Indra named Amaravati abounding in Devas, Yaksas, Apsarases and sages.
>   6. In the interior of Amaravati there is a hall full of diamonds and other gems, which is well known as the assembly Sudharma.
>   7. In it remains the thousand-eyed Indra, husband of Saci, surrounded by Siddhas and other divine beings.
>   8. Indra, revered by all other gods, is the president of this assembly. The great sun is there.
>   9. On its side, as broad and splendid like it, is the city of Agni, called Tejovatī.
>   10. Next is the beautiful city of Vaivasvata (Yama), well known as Samyamini.
>   11. On the fourth direction is the city of Nirrti, called Krsnavati.
>   12. The fifth, on the northern side, is the city of the lord of waters (Varuņa), called Suddhavati.
>   13. Beyond that in the north is the city of Vayu, called Gandhayatī,
>   14. On its right is the beautiful city of Kubera, called Mahodaya with a hall of Vaidūrya gems.
>   15. **On the eighth quarter is the city of Išāna, called Manoharā.**
>   16. This world of gods, prayed for by people in their different aśramas (stages of life ) is svarga (heaven).

So, from above the conclusion is:

1. east: Indra
2. south-east: Agni
3. south: Vaivasvata
4. south-western: Nirṛti
5. western: Varuṇa
6. north-western: Vāyu
7. northern: Kubera
8. north-eastern: Ishana

Answer (score 3):

The term 'Ishana' explained in details [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/ishana) shows how it is connected with Lord Shiva:

> 1) Īśāna:—**One of the five aspects of Śiva**, known collectively as the
>   Pañchabrahmās. They are emanations from the niṣkala-Śiva. Īśāna,
>   according to the Rūpamaṇḍana, should have the colour as pure as that
>   of the crystal; his head should be adorned with a jaṭāmakuṭa
>   ornamented with the crescent moon and his hnads should have the
>   akṣamālā, triśūla, kapāla and abhaya.
>
> The Śrītatvanidhi gives somewhat different description. Īśāna should
>   have, according to this work, five faces; each of these faces should
>   have three eyes; the colour of Īśāna, should be white. This face ought
>   to point to the top. Īśāna should have in his hands abhaya, varada (?)
>   (iṣṭa in the original), aṅkuśa, pāśa, ṭaṅkā, kapāla, ḍhakka (a musical
>   instrument), akṣamāla and śūla.
>
> 2) The deity Īśāna representing the Karmasāda has a perfectly white
>   body resembling the flower of the kunda (a kind of jasmine) or the
>   full moon; having five heads adorned with jaṭā-makuṭas; bearing on
>   each face three eyes, ten arms and two legs. He is standing on a
>   padmāsana and keeps in his right hands the śūla, paraśu, khaḍga, vajra
>   and abhaya and in the left ones the nāga, pāśa, aṅkuśa, ghaṇṭa, and
>   agni. He is beatiful adorned with all ornaments, draped in fine
>   clothes and is with a smiling countenance full of peacefulness.
>
> 3) Īśāna (ईशान):—**One of the eight names of Rudra**, given to him by
>   Brahmā, according to the Pādma-purāṇa. This aspect became the
>   presiding deity over the fire. The corresponding name of the consort
>   is Vikeśī. His son is called Lohitāṅga (Mars).
>
> 4) Īśāna (ईशान):—**Fifth of the eleven emanations of Rudra**
>   (ekādaśa-rudra), according to the Aṃśumadbhedāgama and the Śilparatna.
>   The images of this aspects of Śiva should have three eyes, four arms,
>   jaṭāmakuṭas and be of white colour. It should be draped also in white
>   clothes and be standing erect (samabhaṅga) on a padmapīṭha. It should
>   be adorned with all ornaments and with garlands composed of all
>   flowers and it should keep their front right hand in the abhaya and
>   the front left hand in the varada poses, while it should carry in the
>   back right hand the paraśu and in the back left hand the mṛga.
>
> 5) Īśāna (ईशान):—**Third of the twelve emanations of Rudra**, according to
>   the Rūpamaṇḍana.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Maha Bali's penance, he became the Loka Pālas himself.

Sri Skanda Purana 1.1.18.:

> 140. It has already been mentioned that they went to the auspicious hermitage of Kaśyapa. At that time Bali of great fame became Indra in the city of Devas.
> 141. **By means of his penance, The Asura became the Sun-god himself and blazed. He became Īśa himself and stayed in the north-eastern quarter protecting it, keeping watch over it.**
> 142. Similarly he himself became Nairṛta and Varuṇa, the lord of the waters. Bali then stayed in the north as the lord of wealth (Kubera). Thus Bali directly enjoyed the three worlds himself.
> 143. Thus, O Brāhmaṇas, Bali became eagerly devoted to and engaged in munificent charitable gifts due to the previous practice which the gambler had, because he was engaged in the worship of Śiva.

So, here Ishana in the Lokapālas can mean both Rudra or Sun.

Shatapatha Brahmana 6:1:3.17.:

> "He (Rudra) said to him (Prajāpati), 'Thou art Îsâna (the Ruler).' And because he gave him that name, the Sun became suchlike, **for Îsâna is the Sun,** since the Sun rules over this All. He said, 'So great indeed I am: give me no other name after that!'

[image]

Thus, the 10 Lokpālas (with one additional) are as follows.:

- east.: Indra.
- south-east.: Agni.
- south.: Vaivasvata (Yama).
- south-western.: Nirṛti.
- western.: Varuṇa.
- north-western.: Vāyu.
- northern.: Kubera.
- north-eastern.: Ishana (Sun).
- up.: Brahmā as Swan.
- down.: Vishnu as Boar.
- centre.: Shiva as Sthānu.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..